# What's the dot in finder next to eject button

Tags: macos, finder

What's the dot in finder next to eject button. This:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s just a [Finder tag](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/tag-files-and-folders-mchlp15236/mac).

You can use keywords and/or these colored dots to categorize your files.  For example, you can put a green tag on all financial documents and a red one for medical.  These are just examples.  You can set this up to meet you particular needs